# Select an element using two different classes by partial text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an element which has two distinct classes, unfortunately these class names are partially randomised (The markup is out of my control) e.g.

```
<div class="thing1_abc thing2_def"></div>
```

Where the second part of the class name is random, as in, the `abc` and `def` parts will not be consistent between each page load.

The only thing I could think of was:

```
div[class^="thing1_"][class^="thing2_"]{ }
```

But it seems you can't use multiple class-attribute selectors in a single selector, is there any way to achieve this? Or any alternative that will select this element based on it's classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `^=` relates to the beginning of the whole class atribute string, that's why `thing2_` won't be matched. You could use `*=` instead, like this:

```
div[class*="thing1_"][class*="thing2_"]{ }
```

But that would also match `some_class_thing1_`. That might still filt your needs, if you can be sure that such a class will never exist. But otherwise, I don't see a pure CSS solution.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid matching `some_class_thing1_`, you'd have to do `div[class*=" thing1_"][class*=" thing2_"],div[class^="thing1_"][class*=" thing2_"],div[class*=" thing1_"][class^="thing2_"]{ }`